# ASP MVC 5 - Two forms on page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a web page created in ASP MVC 5 with two forms.
[Screan of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6r4d.png)

The first one "LoginPanel" is a Partial View like this

```
@model UowTest.Models.LoginPanelModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("LoginPanel", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "navbar-form navbar-left" }))
{
    if(!Model.IsLogin)
    { 
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Login, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = Html.PlaceholderFor(m => m.Login) })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = Html.PlaceholderFor(m => m.Password) })
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Zaloguj</button>
    }
    else
    {
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><span>Witaj</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">@Model.UserName</a></li>
        </ul>
    }
}
```

which is added to _Layout.cshtml in top panel section:

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
            ...
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>@Html.Action("LoginPanel", "Account")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

in AccountController I Have HTTP Get and Post method for this form:

```
public ActionResult LoginPanel()
{
    return PartialView(new LoginPanelModel());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoginPanel(LoginPanelModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Login", new { message = "Login lub hasło jest nieprawidłowe!" });
}
```

It worked fine until I added registration view like:

```
@model UowTest.Models.RegisterModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Login)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Login, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = Html.PlaceholderFor(m => m.Login) })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = Html.PlaceholderFor(m => m.Password) })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RepeatedPassword)
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.RepeatedPassword, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = Html.PlaceholderFor(m => m.RepeatedPassword) })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = Html.PlaceholderFor(m => m.FirstName) })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = Html.PlaceholderFor(m => m.LastName) })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = Html.PlaceholderFor(m => m.Email) })
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Zarejestruj</button>
}
```

with AccountController methods:

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    return View(new RegisterModel());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

When I hit register button, it calls

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
```

and when the ModelState is not valid i return the Register view to show validation messages, but insted of see this page, something call

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoginPanel(LoginPanelModel model)
```

what cause the error:

```
    System.Web.HttpException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.
  Source=System.Web
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  WebEventCode=0
  StackTrace:
       w System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
       w System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage)
       w System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
       w System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
       w System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter)
       w System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
       w System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName)
       w ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() w c:\Users\Lenovo T430s\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\UowTest\UowTest\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml:wiersz 30
       w System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       w System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       w System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
       w System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer)
       w System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c__DisplayClass3.<RenderPageCore>b__2(TextWriter writer)
       w System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer)
       w System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.WriteTo(TextWriter writer, HelperResult content)
       w System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result)
       w System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body)
       w System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext()
       w System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
       w System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
       w System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
       w System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
       w System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
       w System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
       w System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
  InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions.
       Source=System.Web.Mvc
       StackTrace:
            w System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
            w System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
            w System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
            w System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
            w System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
            w System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
            w System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            w System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            w System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
            w System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
            w System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            w System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
            w System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            w System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
            w System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
            w System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
            w System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            w System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)
            w System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            w System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
            w System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
            w System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
            w System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            w System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            w System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
            w System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            w System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
            w System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
            w System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
            w System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            w System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
            w System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper.<>c__DisplayClassa.<EndProcessRequest>b__9()
            w System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Wrap>b__3()
            w System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap[TResult](Func`1 func)
            w System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Action action)
            w System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
            w System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
       InnerException:
```

In _Layout.cshtml in line where Login Partial View is created.

Answer (score 0):

try returning PatrialView instead of view.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }

    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Comment: It is not a solution, because when I return PartialView the page doesn't use my layaut and register page is ugly, but the error doesn't occured.

Comment: why don't you make the register a partial view,,from your image it seems like register is a partial view.

Comment: Register is standard view and use _Layout witch contains LoginPanel partial view. Make the Register as PartialView maybe solve my problem, but a need all view with form make as partial, becauase all view use _Layout. I think that problem is in redirect in LoginPanel post method, but how can I do redirection after model invalid.

Comment: on your screenshot you have maked the register with red, mysuggestion is  that section would be a partial, and for model invalid you don't want to redirect them anywhere else rather list the validation errors on the register page(i, e user exists, or email not valid etc). and once user has registered succfully you would ideally redirect to home(which would be another partial)